# downloading a library in python3 env through conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, spacy

I'm trying to download the spaCy library in a new python3 environment.

Here's what I have:

```
python3 -m venv .env
source .env/bin/activate
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
conda install -c conda-forge spacy-lookups-data
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

The error I got was: /Users/KerryChowChow/Dropbox/2019data_art/.env/bin/python3: No module named spacy

I have both python2.7 and python3 under the environment. Tried both `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` and `python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`
Both resulted in the same error.

I think it's a location problem.

I have previously successfully downloaded spaCy via the command line `conda install -c conda-forge spacy` so spaCy must be SOMEWHERE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Conda will not install things into the python virtual environment you created. If you'd like to make a conda virtual environment with a specific version of python and then install python packages into the conda environment you can do the following:

```
conda create -n .env python=x.x anaconda
source activate .env
conda install -n .env -c conda-forge spacy
```

If you'd like to just use your python virtual environment instead and install space there follow these steps (I will assume .env doesn't exist here for completeness).

```
python3 -m venv .env
source .env/bin/activate
pip3 install spacy
```

Comment: the second option doesn't seem to work: "Usage:   
  pip3 <command> [options]

no such option: -U"

Comment: sorry, that was from their website. And I left off `install` but edited it in. try it now.

Answer (score 0):

I used `pip install` and python3 instead and it worked!

```
python -m venv .env
source .env/bin/activate
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

somehow, using `conda install` isn't working.

Comment: `venv` and `conda` are two different tools, and probably aren't even using the same Python interpreter on your system - you can't just mix and match them. If you create a conda environment and install into it with conda (or pip) it should work.